# remove elements with "display: none;" for email using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, email

I'm generating a email from a web page and taking a section of the page and putting it into the email. The problem is the section of code has elements with "display: none;" and some email clients don't recognise the display:none property which then displays unwanted elements in the email.

I want to remove these elements using some simple javascript i already remove elements with certain classes now i want to remove elements with certain styles, the styles are inline. I'm using jquery with the site.

Comment: Just FYI (since you're new here), it's best practice to accept an answer (by clicking the tick next to it) *if one sufficiently answers your question*. Feel free to wait for one that does or to ask for clarifications, etc in comments.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the [`:hidden`](http://api.jquery.com/hidden-selector/) selector:

```
$(":hidden").remove();
```

Comment: Huh. Thanks, that was useful. It also removed the `<head>` tag and all its contents though! Easy to fix, but I wasn't expecting that to happen :D

Answer (score 2):

```
  $("div[style*='display:none']").remove();
```

Comment: This is probably better than the ":hidden" selector, as the ":hidden" selector will also pick up the "visibility: hidden" style.

Comment: @Graza: Not since jQuery 1.3.2, as can read in the docs linked from cletus' answer.

Comment: This solution only works for elements that have a style attribute, but they also could be hidden by plain CSS.